# How can I add pages written using Tapestry5 to a web application already written in Tapestry4?

Tags: tapestry

I'm trying to add pages written with Tapestry5 to a web application written with Tapestry 4 on Apache Tomcat. Assuming I have the necessary jars in $tomcat/shared/lib.

I made a basic form template and corresponding java class to test with, following the example [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/forms1), then replaced an existing html file with the new one, but I'm getting stuck with a DocumentParseException caused by the page specification (.page) file having an "unexpected public id of '-//Apache Software Foundation//Tapestry Specification 5.3//EN'" whenever I try to access the page through tomcat. If I change that line in the page specification file back to "Tapestry Specification 4.0//EN" I get a different exception saying I need to implement the IPage interface in the java class.

This is my first time working on a project involving Tapestry and I couldn't find anything online specific to this issue so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid Tapestry5 and Tapestry4 carry the same name, but are very different. I think you will just need to recreate these pages using Tapestry4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that for a legacy application and the process took about 3 months to have the all services migrated and the first pages running. Here's an overview. I cannot post code for various reasons.

1. Update to tapestry 4.1.6. (can be long and painful if you haven't).
2. Make sure tapestry4 servlet url-pattern is something like /t4/* and t5 ignored paths contains /t4/.*.
3. Initialize t5 request globals for t4 requests. (sub-class t4 servlet and override the doService method).
4. Initialize hivemind and t4 request globals for t5 requests. (contribute an HttpServletRequestFilter in the t5 module between "after:StoreIntoGlobals" and "before:EndOfRequest").
5. Create an ObjectProvider for hivemind for t5 services.
6. Migrate all services you can to t5 ioc. (It can be tricky since you can't use hivemind services directly, but you can use the hivemind registry behind the scenes).
7. (Optional) Create link components for tapestry4 and t5 that automatically give you links for tapestry4 or tapestry5 pages with that same name and handle activation context.
   You can use PageRenderLinkSource for t5 links and the external service for t4.
8. For every service with state create wrappers for hivemind.

If your codebase is not large or extremely complex it's definately not worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Tapestry 4 and Tapestry 5 side-by-side (the package names are different, for just this reason) ... but they know nothing of each other, and can't interact directly. This is just like the way you could have a single WAR with multiple servlets; the different applications can only communicate via URLs, or shared state in the HttpSession.